# Why I can not use Ext.grid.Grid?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have a problem with the `ExtJS 6` framework. When I use `Ext.grid.Panel` it works, but I want to use `Ext.grid.Grid`. What is the difference between `Ext.grid.Panel` and `Ext.grid.Grid`?

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Grid', {
    columns: [{
        width: 200,
        dataIndex: 'firstName',
        flex: 1,
        text: 'First Name'
    }, {
        width: 200,
        dataIndex: 'lastName',
        flex: 1,
        text: 'Last Name'
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `Ext.grid.Grid` if you don't know the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Ext.grid.Panel` class belongs to the Classic framework, used for desktop websites. The `Ext.grid.Grid` class belongs to the Modern framework, used primarily for mobile websites.

If you want to use `Ext.grid.Grid`, you need to switch to the Modern framework. The ExtJS documentation covers how to select a framework to use (including how to use both frameworks within a single application).

Answer (score 1):

If you go through docs it clearly says `Ext.grid.Grid` component is only present in modern toolkit .
If you want to use Grid in classic toolkit you have to use `Ext.panel.grid` .

[here is the link to follow](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.grid.Grid.html)

[image]